# Single Web API controller per resource or less controllers with more custom actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller

I want to expose most of my business layer methods to a Web API project to allow for broader consumption.

One idea is to have one Web API controller per resource.

The other idea is to have one controller per logical business part and use attribute routing to expose the relative methods.

I like the second approach, that results to less controllers.

What are the disadvantages of NOT having one controller per resource?

**Additional Info:**

This API will live in an intranet and will serve support applications that need data from our 2-3 master applications (ERP,Payroll,Barcode e.t.c)

A resource for this APi would be business entities that are defined in our business layer assembly. They will be simple objects and complex ones. Examples:

- Inventory Items
- Customers
- Items per Customer
- Current loading pickslips
- Present production data

e.t.c

**Example:**

I want to expose methods like `GetCustomerListByArea` or `GetItemsListPerCategory`.

What then? Should i create another controller or use custom controller actions and attribute routing and put it in the existing controllers?

**A link with some more info:**

[REST vs. RPC in ASP.NET Web API? Who cares; it does both.](http://encosia.com/rest-vs-rpc-in-asp-net-web-api-who-cares-it-does-both/)

Very nice , rather old, article explaining my question. But it does not go deeper in actual saying how to orginize controllers. In areas? Or just folders?

Comment: what be a 'resource'?

Comment: added some additional information to the original post

Comment: Our controllers are just that...controllers. We use them as an access layer to Service Handlers which then handle the business logic. From the Service Handlers, we refer to an NHibernate layer which creates the Transaction between our application and the data (repository)...so we organize our repositories by the business entities, but our service controllers are more closely related to the action...which could return an object comprised of various business entities...depends on what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This boils down to a simple design principle - separation of concerns (SoC), you should have a think about what functionality from your business layer you want to expose and create controllers based on that.

From your example above, you *might* create a `ProductController` and `CustomerController`, which could expose the following endpoints:

```
GET /api/customer/1234        # gets customer by id
POST /api/customer/create     # creates a new customer
GET /api/customer/1234/items  # gets all items for a customer
GET /api/product/9876         # gets a product by id
POST /api/product/create      # creates a new product
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Lets say i want to expose some other data about the customer, for example i want to expose methods like `GetCustomerListByArea` or `GetItemsListPerCategory`. What then? Should i create another controller or use custom controller actions and attribute routing and put it in the existing controllers?

Comment: No, I wouldn't create another controller, the methods you mention look to me like they're filtering a data set, so you'd have something like this: `GET /api/customer/byarea/sydney`, your controller method might look like this `public IEnumerable<Customer> ByArea(string area) {}`.