# Web Api - Controller Per Database Entity or per UI Screen

Tags: asp.net, architecture, asp.net-web-api

I am using web api in my project to expose data which in turn is intended to be used by a mobile application and a web application.

I want to know what is the best practice to expose data.

For instance, I have a customer registration form in which I am capturing Customer details including city and country.

One way to expose the data is to have separate Controllers for cities and countries and make separate calls to both on the customer registration form in order to load the data for cities and countries.

The issue with this approach would be that if I have to load hundred fields, I will have to make hundred different call to the api to load the data and hence the application will be slow.

Second approach would be design the api layer in such a way that one controller expose all the lookup data (cities, countries) required for a form/screen (customer registration). In this case I will have to make a single call to the api to get all the required data.

It feels like, using the second approach I am violating separation of concern.

Which way to go?

Comment: I would lean towards keeping a controller per entity, creating as few as possible. In cases where I would need to load more than 10 fields, I would either move that server side to be compiled in the view, or in the case of an SPA, create a single controller method that returned all of the data needed for the form, rather than requesting data from 10+ controllers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148951/single-web-api-controller-per-resource-or-less-controllers-with-more-custom-acti

Comment: tnx @Prime03 .. so your are saying, in the customer example, we should expose the data via separate controllers (cities, countries) as well as via another controller in which all of the data for a view is returned if the fields or more in order to avoid multiple calls. In that case don't you think we would be repeating ourselves?

Comment: In the customer example, if I only needed to load cities/countries/phone types/address types, etc... I would load them from their respective controllers. After the number of http requests required to supply this data on the page passed a performance/resource threshold, I would create another method that returned all of the required data in a single json array. It all depends on your architecture. You are trading some DRY points for some performance points. The art is in the balance. I should note, I've never had to do this for a form.

Comment: Exactly.. that was the point of the post.. when should we go for performance vs when for design best practices :)

Comment: You obviously want to make as few http calls on page load as necessary on any given page. If you need to make 100 http requests, consolidate it to 1 or 2. The issue with your question is "if I have to load hundred fields". Do you, or do you not? If not, start with controllers that properly encapsulate an entity (address rather than city and country). If you need to reduce requests, reuse your existing methods in a new method to consolidate.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just split UI and API layers?

I do not think you should create API to fetch countries or whatever else side-references if they are not core parts of your domain.

I guess you should just expose `api/v1/users` resource endpoint for user registration, which expects a valid user data for registration.

Plus you should expose `/users` UI, which will generate full UI, including all the lists you need and present it to the user. This UI controller will call your domain model internally, not via API to get all the details, needed to generate UI. And then UI on the client side will call your API controller with user selected data to register user.

Will that suite your development model?

Comment: calling /user and binding the lists in UI will work in the scenario if I am using web and the logic for rendering the UI is in server along with the configuration (db user, password) to connect to the data store and get the lists data but how can it be done in case of a mobile application as ideally the application should not know how to connect to the data store directly.

Comment: @ZedBee Well, I see. of course, mobile application is a bit different case. In this case you would probably need to expose everything you have in your DB via REST somehow.

Comment: exactly, that is the goal, to design a single rest api to be consumed by different applications like mobile, web, desktop etc..

Comment: @ZedBee No, an api controller per REST resource. REST entities do not always map directly to your models. For example, your `Cheque` model may have `pay` method. But in REST you will have "virtual" `/transaction` resource, which, upon creation, signifies `pay` operation.

Comment: tnx.. got that .. +1 on post :)